# Ruby on Rails - How to Query on model/condition on controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel, named-scope

I'm using rails 3.2.3 and have a questions about queries.

I've read that it is favorable using arel instead of named scopes.

Basically in my app, when a user logs in, I want him to see the products that he created.
So instead of having in my *controllers index*:

```
products=Product.find(:all)
```

I was looking for something like

```
products=Product.find(:all, :conditions....)
```

The thing is, my User and Product models have a HABTM relation (it really has to be) and I don't know how to join those tables so that only the products inserted by the `current_user` are displayed (the insertion is working correctly)

Do I have to add a search method in my Product model?
Or this can be accomplished by passing `:conditions` in the index controller?

Basically the logic is:

->Get all the products

->inner joining with the products_users HABTM table and get all the products where products_users.user_id = current_user.id. Return the results.

I don't know if I'm missing something here...any tips on how to code this? I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if user_sighed_in?
  @products = current_user.products
else
  @products = Product.scoped
end
```

ofc u have to define association in User model

```
has_many :products
```

Comment: It's preferably to not use `.all` in your controller. You can return relation instead: `Product.scoped`. The reason here is to be prepared for the future where you may use fragment caching -- you won't be happy to know that expensive DB-query still gets triggered although you fetch your page content from the cache.

Comment: lol, ofc it is just conversation of his code... at least he needs to scope or paginate results( anyway i voted up for your good comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you have associated User and Products models - this code `@products = current_user.products` will return products of `current_user`.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the products of current user this will do the trick

```
   current_user.products
```